# Get UnsafePointer<UInt8> to Int to write an encoded Int to a stream

Tags: ios, swift

How do you get a pointer to a number variable? E.g. convert get an `UnsafePointer<UInt8>` that points to the storage containing a Swift `Int`. I need to write the `Int` to a stream.

My example:

```
public static func writeToOutputStream(text: String!, outputStream:NSOutputStream!){
    let encodedDataArray = [UInt8](text.utf8)
    //send length of the data so the server knows when the message ends.
    outputStream.write(encodedDataArray.count, maxLength: 4)
    outputStream.write(encodedDataArray, maxLength: encodedDataArray.count)
}
```

I need `encodedDataArray.count` to be an `UnsafePointer<UInt8>` if I want to send the data length too.

Comment: Do you want to get a pointer to an Int or cast an Int to a pointer?

Comment: Get a pointer to an Int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `withUnsafePointer`, like this:

```
let outputStream = NSOutputStream(toMemory: ())
outputStream.open()

var count: Int = 0x01020304 // = encodedDataArray.count in your program
withUnsafePointer(&count) { (pointer: UnsafePointer<Int>) -> Void in
    outputStream.write(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(pointer), maxLength: 4)
}

outputStream.propertyForKey(NSStreamDataWrittenToMemoryStreamKey)
```

Result:

```
<04030201>
```

Note that it'll write the bytes in little-endian order (because all platforms on which Swift currently runs are little-endian). If you want to write in big-endian, use `encodedDataArray.count.bigEndian`.

Comment: "because all platforms on which Swift currently runs are little-endian"
Should I force it to little-endian just in case this changes?

Comment: It's extremely unlikely to change, but on the other hand saying `encodedDataArray.count.littleEndian` makes it clear that you thought about it.